# Fixing installation of bash script

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, bash, script

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Playing with catkin_lint, I found out about this mistake:

```
$ catkin lint -W2 --pkg my_pkg
my_pkg: warning: file 'scripts/foo.sh' is executable but not installed
```

but in my CMakelists I have:

```
install(DIRECTORY scripts/
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}  # with or without a "/scripts" here the result doesn't change
    PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

and have also tried with:

```
install(FILES
    scripts/foo.sh
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}  # with or without a "/scripts" here the result doesn't change
)
```

**All these methods still leave the warning on the catkin lint side!**

In all four cases I get a correct installation of the script in the install directory, but I have to manually `chmod +x` it. The output from rosrun is:

```
$ rosrun my_pkg foo.sh
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named foo.sh below /home/<user>/catkin_ws/install/share/my_pkg
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/<user>/catkin_ws/install/share/my_pkg/foo.sh   # or ...my_pkg/scripts/foo.sh
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320040/fixing-installation-of-bash-script/) by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 589 on 2019-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-11**:
<del>This could just be a limitation of `catkin_lint`. Perhaps posting an issue on [the tracker](https://github.com/fkie/catkin_lint/issues) would be in order.</del>

Or, it could be because for shell scripts, the type should be set to `PROGRAMS`, not `FILES` or `DIRECTORY`.

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2019-04-12**:
I was being wary of opening another issue for nothing like last time, and for a good reason it seems. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct syntax is with `PROGRAMS` instead of `FILES` and using the `BIN` destination, not the `SHARE` one.

```
install(PROGRAMS scripts/foo.sh
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}/scripts
)
```

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2